# An angular service for passing objects between pages

Tags: angularjs

In my web application i start feeling the need to pass objects from one page controller to another, not just parameters in the route. I think that this can make my application faster and the code clean. By page controllers i mean controllers corresponding to `$routeProvider` routes.

I think i can easily implement this with a service, say `pageBroker`. This service will take a route and an object, and load the page corresponding to the route:

```
pageBroker.load('/assign-task/', { task: { ... } });
```

That page would find the object in a special section of the service:

```
pageBroker.pageData.task;
```

Page data can be reset for every route change.

This is not an implementation problem, but a software design problem. Usually similar questions get closed on Stack overflow, but i will try once again: is this a good or a bad idea? Is it suitable for the Angular architecture? Why yes or why not?

Comment: What if the user goes to the second page without going through the first one?

Comment: Good point. This i what stateful locations are for. I will have to add some logic for handling this case, i wonder if the benefits are more than the costs, but this is the kind of drawbacks that i am trying to target with my question

Comment: Have you considered using ui-router? It does much more than ngRoute, and among other things, allows passing parameters between states: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state.

Comment: Maybe a concept of mandatory fallback may fix this issue? https://gist.github.com/danse/83dc2a8014f738f28a24

Comment: I considered it, it is very powerful and i regret not having included it in the app since from the beginning. So how do they solve the problem of an user going to a second page without going through the first one? I guess in that case you would set `location` to `false` in the options of `$state.go`

Comment: It's just an idea, and I don't even know if you can pass arbitrary parameters. But you should, IMO, pass the ID of the data (this ID being part of the URL) along with the data itself. If the user goes directly to the URL, you will get the ID without the data, and fall back to getting the data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with AngularJS, I would say using Services is a good approach, always worked well for me. (But if anyone thinks differently, I will be more than happy to hear your thoughts on this)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('Data', function() {
    return {message: "I'm data from a service and I can be shared between multiple controllers"}
})

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data){
  $scope.data = Data;
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Data){
  $scope.data = Data;
}
```

and in your view you can use it like

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
      <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
      <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can even bind the Data.message to a model in the controller scope and whenever you change the model, the data-binding will change also on the Service and consequently on the other Controller (But sometimes you might need to call $apply).

This video might be useful to you: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers